# Can I create OneNote links that open in the desktop app instead of the web app?

Tags: macos, onenote

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/644416/can-i-create-onenote-links-that-open-in-the-desktop-app-instead-of-the-web-app) is at superuser.com but I can't get any of the answers to work on macOS.

Onenote gives you two links and the 2nd one should open in the app.

```
onenote:https://xxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/my_name/Documents/Anotebookname/Notebook.one#ASectionName/etc/etc/&end
```

I've tested putting the onenote:link into a few apps and it only opens up the web app.  If I put them directly into safari, then that works and opens up the OneNote Desktop app.

My goal is to put links to specific OneNote pages into my the notes area of the Things App.

Does something have to go in the front of it to tell the app(IE, Things) to redirect to the App or Safari?

Answer (score 3):

From looking at this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198125/how-can-i-open-an-application-url),  manually adding a **/** **/** (forward slash x 2) to the front of the HTTP works.

IE:

```
onenote://https://xxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/my_name/Documents/Anotebookname/Notebook.one#ASectionName/etc/etc/&end
```

Comment: Interesting workaround, perhaps this should be reported as a bug to Things devs?

Comment: @grg . I don't think it's a Things problem as it's the same in Apple Notes.  Also in Notes,  for onenote:http://..etc..  only the http:// turns into a link and the onenote: stays as text.   And then add the whole line turns to a link if I add the // to the front of http.